# How to group transactions by year and month?

Tags: python, pandas

I've checked all the suggested answers here but each one I try I think I break my code more.

Sample of my data:

```
print(transactions.head())

                      loc  amount  local_date
0                    RAIL     8.1  2016-09-30
1      LINK NETWORK LIMIT     4.0  2016-10-02
2          CHOCOLATE CAFE     3.0  2016-10-03
3         Four Star Pizza     9.7  2016-10-03
4                  Cinema    10.0  2016-10-04
```

I just want to group by year, and month and sum transactions.

For example my expected outcome:

```
2019 Jan  100
     Feb  123 
     Mar  150
     etc.
2018 Jan  200
     Feb  150
     Mar  211
     etc.
```

And what I have tried (basically all the suggested answers)

```
transactions.set_index('local_date').groupby([(transactions.index.year),(transactions.index.month)])['amount'].sum()


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-332-64938cfdee85> in <module>
----> 1 transactions.set_index('local_date').groupby([(transactions.index.year),(transactions.index.month)])['amount'].sum()

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'year'
```

```
transactions.set_index('local_date').groupby([(transactions.index.dt.year),(transactions.index.dt.month)])['amount'].sum()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-334-150c05241676> in <module>
----> 1 transactions.set_index('local_date').groupby([(transactions.index.dt.year),(transactions.index.dt.month)])['amount'].sum()


AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

```
transactions.set_index('local_date').groupby([(transactions.index.to_series().dt.year),(transactions.index.to_series.()dt.month)])['amount'].sum()


AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I'm losing my mind. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['local_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['local_date'])
df.groupby([df['local_date'].dt.year,df['local_date'].dt.month])['amount'].sum()

local_date  local_date
2016        9              8.1
            10            26.7
```

**if you prefere show the name of the month:**

```
new_df=df.groupby([df['local_date'].dt.year,df['local_date'].dt.month_name()])['amount'].sum().to_frame('Total amount')
print(new_df)
                       Total amount
local_date local_date              
2016       October             26.7
           September            8.1
```

---

```
new_df=df.groupby(df['local_date'].dt.to_period('M')).amount.sum().to_frame('Total_amount')
print(new_df)

            Total_amount
local_date              
2016-09              8.1
2016-10             26.7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby `year, month`:

```
(transaction.groupby([transaction.local_date.dt.year,
                     transaction.local_date.dt.month])
          .sum())
```

Output:

```
                       amount
local_date local_date        
2016       9              8.1
           10            26.7
```

If you want the month name, replace `.dt.month` with `.dt.month_name()`, but you will need to do extra for the correct ordering:

```
                       amount
local_date local_date        
2016       October       26.7
           September      8.1
```